# How to get an access token for a simple Dropbox app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-api, aws-lambda

My client has a Dropbox folder with files they want to make available on their web site in a custom widget we're building. I understand how to use the Dropbox API v2 to get the list, but where does the OAuth access token come from?

- Do I need to create a formal Dropbox app just to do this?
- Does my client need to create an app since it's their Dropbox folder?
- Is an "app" even necessary? I'm hoping it's not.

(The access token is protected behind an AWS Lambda function, in case you're wondering.)

Comment: Explain downvote please.

Comment: No reason to downvote this question. I upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox follows the oauth standard. So, to consume its rest api you have to create an access token for authorization.

You have to create an app on dropbox which gives you necessary details to create an access token. Your client won't need to create an app. You can create an app and use your client's credential to authorize to your app which create an access token. You can use in Dropbox API.

Follow the link after creating app to create access token : 
https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-authorize

Hope this helps!

**Update**:

For the scenario described in the question, the answer is to create an app in the client's account and use its generated access token. There is no need to create a full OAuth flow, nor does it need to be a production app.

Comment: This won't work. 1. I can't use my client's credentials when I create an app using my account. 2. I do not want to (and should not have to) write code for an OAuth flow just to get *one* access token.

Comment: You can "generate" an OAuth 2 access token for your own account using the "Generate" button on your app's page on the App Console, without going through the OAuth flow: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps

Comment: @Greg So to get one for the client's account, I will have to create an app on their account -- is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, you can only "generate" a token for the account that owns the app. Otherwise, you need to use the OAuth flow.

Comment: One more Q, @Greg: Will I need to "apply for production" for that app, or will the access token work fine given my scenario? It's not a public app.

Comment: If you don't need to link more than 50 users, you don't need to apply for production. You can find more information here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#production-approval